# How to extract Data from text log file to specific columns in CSV - LogParser preferred

Tags: csv, logparser

Hi I have a large log file the data is in following format :

```
125856  status-created 856598745 2000
125857  status-created 857598745 500
125858  status-created 856658745 3500
```

I need to export this data to separate columns in CSV file.

Can you please help me doing this with `LogParser`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
logparser "SELECT Field1 AS Foo, Field2 AS bar, Field3 AS Whatever, Field4 AS AnotherField INTO output.csv FROM log.txt" -i:TSV -headerRow:OFF -o:CSV
```